# Vim の nnoremap コマンドの打ち方がわからない

Tags: vim

vimのプラグインであるdefx.vimをインストールしたのですが、以下のコマンドはどのように打てば良いのかわかりません。

```
nnoremap <silent><buffer><expr> o defx#do_action('open_or_close_tree')
```

Comment: 参考にしたインストール方法や、どんな動作を期待して、どういう操作をしたか、そしてどんな動作が起きたか（または動作が起きなかったか）も書いていただけますか？差し支えなければ設定ファイル（vimrc）全体を追記してください。Vim自体の操作がわからないのか、プラグインのインストールや設定がうまくいってないだけなのかがより伝わりやすくなります。

Answer (score 2):

[`nnoremap`](https://vim-jp.org/vimdoc-ja/map.html#:nnoremap) というのは Vim のExコマンドです。

Exコマンドは、Vim 上でノーマルモード中に `:` （コロン） をタイプすることで入力待機状態になるので、そこで入力・実行できます。また、`nnoremap` などは、`.vimrc` に記述することが多いでしょう。その場合 `:` は省略可能です。